# Execute different functions on conditon

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I would like to do something like this:

If `isPlaying = false;` then the functions `nextTrack()` and `previousTrack()` should only invoke `loadTrack(track_index)` and not `playTrack()` otherwise they should invoke both `loadTrack(track_index)` and `playTrack()`

How can I do it?

```js
 let playpause_btn = document.querySelector(".playpause-track");
    let next_btn = document.querySelector(".next-track");
    let prev_btn = document.querySelector(".prev-track");

    let track_index = 0;
    let isPlaying = false;
 
 
 function playpauseTrack() {
      if (!isPlaying) playTrack();
      else pauseTrack();
    }

    function playTrack() {
      curr_track.play();
      isPlaying = true;   
  }
    
    function pauseTrack() {
      curr_track.pause();
      isPlaying = false;
  }

    function nextTrack() {
      if (track_index < track_list.length - 1) 
        track_index += 1;
      else track_index = 0;
        loadTrack(track_index);
       playTrack();    
    }

    function prevTrack() {
      if (track_index > 0)
        track_index -= 1;
      else track_index = track_list.length;
      loadTrack(track_index);
      playTrack();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function nextTrack() {
    if (track_index < track_list.length - 1) {
        track_index += 1;
    }else{
        track_index = 0;
    }
    loadTrack(track_index);
    if(isPlaying == true){ playTrack(); }    
}
```

or better

```
function nextTrack() {
    track_index = (track_index + 1) % track_list.length;
    loadTrack(track_index);
    if(isPlaying == false){ playTrack(); }    
}
```

`prevTrack()` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much!  If  I change false to true, it works as i want....

Comment: function nextTrack() {
    track_index = (track_index + 1) % track_list.length;
    loadTrack(track_index);
    if(isPlaying == true){ playTrack(); }    
}

function prevTrack() {
    track_index = (track_index - 1) % track_list.length;
    loadTrack(track_index);
    if(isPlaying == true){ playTrack(); }    
}

Comment: The only detail that does not work is that when I am on the first song on the list and I click on previous it does not take me to the last song on the list. But when I'm on the last song and I click  on next, it does take me to the first song on the list.  But it's a detail and it doesn't matter so much, again thanks ...

Comment: 1. Fixed my answer. 2. You need to do `index = (index + len - 1) % len`  for decrementing because modulo of negative numbers doesn't always work.